# Windows 7 locked on admin account which doesn't have a password enabled

Tags: windows-7, administrator

Windows 7 Ultimate seems to be locked. I recall having Cygwin & Firefox running, Adobe updates were installing, then all freezing... I have manually killed some processes in the Task Bar, but it did not help. I had to turn off my computer with keeping the start button pressed, because other things did not work.

Now the systems loads, but whenever I try to press on a button or an icon, it gets highlighted, shows menu upon right-click, also responds to menu chosen and pressed with right click only. Alt-F4 on desktop shows Shut-down menu. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and subsequent menu opens a Task Bar, but only right-click works in it. I don't remember how I got to see this (possibly pushing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> repeatedly), but it has shown my user account button with "locked" underneath. Maybe my account is not locked in fact, it's just I have got that "locked" due to my manipulations.

I tried Safe Mode pressing F8, but it was the same thing. Now I cannot enter Safe Mode for some reason.

After I boot my computer and do nothing Adobe Updated icon still shows in the bottom right.
The processes in Task Bar looked normal - on top is Windows Explorer, Desktop Windows Manager, Taskbar, antivirus.

Now mouse even stopped working.
This is an account with admin rights, no password, because it's a home desktop (Lenovo).

Can you help me with this little info I could put together?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by booting from a password reset CD. Most of these do not only allow you to reset the password, but also to unlock an account.

After that, boot into windows and please set a password.  No password is asking for problems, either from people playing a prank or from people who compromise your desktop for more nefarious reasons.

Comment: Thank you. Where do I get that password reset CD? Do you have some specific product on CD in mind?

Comment: Personally I use this one: <http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/> It is old but works well. There are many other tools though, all doing more or less the same.

Comment: Thank a lot for the answers! I figured it out. It was not a Windows lockout problem. It was a mouse failure problem. But thanks for the answer, it's good to know!