# Windows 7 locked on admin account which doesn't have a password enabled

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 locked on admin account which doesn't have a password enabled](https://superuser.com/questions/457586/windows-7-locked-on-admin-account-which-doesnt-have-a-password-enabled)

Windows 7 seems to be locked. I recall manually killing some processes in the Task Bar before that happened, but nothing much. I had to turn off my computer with keeping the start button pressed, because other things did not work.

Now the systems loads, but whenever I try to press on a button or an icon, it gets highlighted, may show menu upon right-click, no no action. Alt-4 on desktop shows Shut-down menu.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and subsequent menu opens a Task bar, but no action is allowed. 
I don't remember how I got to see this (possibly pushing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> repeatedly), but it has shown my user account button with "locked" underneath.

This is an account with admin rights, no password, because it's a home desktop (Lenovo).

Can you help me with this little info I could put together?

Comment: Next time, please just wait for your question to be migrated and don't post it again. Thank you!